# PDF tag wiki uneditable

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, tag-wiki

There is no link/button that will allow editing of the [pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pdf) tag wiki. Improve this tag wiki pink just redirects back to the tag wiki page.

What is going on?

(Note [DanielBeck also has this problem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3396270#3396270), so it is not just a suggested editing issue)

**Update:** Even after Random edited the wiki he problem is not resolved

Comment: +1, I can reproduce. I can get to the [info](http://superuser.com/tags/pdf/info) page in the normal manner, but clicking the "Edit Tag Wiki" button is indeed bringing me back to that same page. Even going directly to the tag's edit page apparent URL ([`http://superuser.com/edit-tag-wiki/553`](http://superuser.com/edit-tag-wiki/553)) doesn't work. But it is working on other tags, as expected. How strange :/

Comment: Tis strange that there is a tag a mod cannot edit...

Comment: I can, however, edit it by going to the [revisions page](http://superuser.com/posts/247236/revisions) & then hitting edit on the [last revision](http://superuser.com/posts/247236/edit/abe37b98-a845-42a8-8a10-f9d254a983b6)

Comment: There is also no pending suggest edit.

Comment: @Sathya Interesting workaround. Not sure we should though, as this seems like a bug and editing might interfere with analysis.

Comment: @DanielBeck was tempted to go about and edit to see if it works, but as you said, it might end up causing other changes. Left it as it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pdf) tag wiki was deleted at some point and any attempts to reach the main edit page would redirect back to its /info page, even for moderators.

How was it deleted? There was a hole in our permission checks - moderators were allowed to pretty much delete anything, including tag wikis (although, this is not exposed in the UI currently).

The gates have been barred and all wikis should now be editable again (based on privileges).

Comment: php or pdf wiki??

Comment: We're talking about PDF, so I guess that was just a mixup.

Comment: @soandos I have [PHP](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/168518385087430656) seared in my mind, for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

`http://superuser.com/edit-tag-wiki/553` sends an HTTP 302 Found reply to redirect to the tag wiki page `/tags/pdf/info`. I don't think there's anything we can do to analyze this further.

Request:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://superuser.com/tags/pdf/info
```

Response:

```
Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2012 20:02:43 GMT
Content-Length: 131
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /tags/pdf/info
Cache-Control: private
```

---

With full privileges, the button to the edit page is identical to other tag wikis', no difference there:

> `<div class="post-menu"><form method='get' action='#' class='form-submit'><input type='button' value='Edit Tag Wiki' onclick="window.location.href='/edit-tag-wiki/553'"/></form><a href="/posts/247236/revisions">history</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href='#' id='show-wiki-excerpt'>show excerpt</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/posts/247237/revisions">excerpt history</a></div>        <br class="cbt">`
>
> `<div class="post-menu"><form method='get' action='#' class='form-submit'><input type='button' value='Edit Tag Wiki' onclick="window.location.href='/edit-tag-wiki/552'"/></form><a href="/posts/230635/revisions">history</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href='#' id='show-wiki-excerpt'>show excerpt</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/posts/230636/revisions">excerpt history</a></div>        <br class="cbt">`

---

The `PDF` tag wiki editing page on SO can be reached without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Since posting analysis in the comments is difficult, I declare this community wiki to be used for sharing our findings!

### Normal tag wiki:

```
<div class="post-menu">

    <form class="form-submit" action="#" method="get">
        <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/edit-tag-wiki/702'"
               value="Edit Tag Wiki">
    </form>

    <a href="/posts/196614/revisions">history</a>
    <span class="lsep">|</span>
    <a id="show-wiki-excerpt" href="#">show excerpt</a>
    <span class="lsep">|</span>
    <a href="/posts/196615/revisions">excerpt history</a>

</div>
```

### pdf tag wiki:

```
<div class="post-menu">

    <a href="/posts/247236/revisions">history</a>
    <span class="lsep">|</span>
    <a id="show-wiki-excerpt" href="#">show excerpt</a>
    <span class="lsep">|</span>
    <a href="/posts/247237/revisions">excerpt history</a>

</div>
```

The markup for the `Edit Tag Wiki` button is completely missing and the `excerpt history` link (https://superuser.com/posts/247237/revisions) is broken.

When examining the [latest](https://superuser.com/revisions/10cf01bb-fbf9-4a86-a6f9-3da2742fff00/view-source) history source, there is an **extra** newline at the end of the post (compared to the '[normal](https://superuser.com/revisions/1d8b9383-b2aa-452e-ad95-7d141f5a7ced/view-source)' tag wiki above). Could this be causing the bug? Can someone with tag wiki edit privileges try replicating this on a different tag?

Comment: That extra newline isn't the problem. Was/is still not allowing people to edit the tag repo before that revision

Comment: Ah. I see that now. The problem lies beneath the surface!

Comment: @random How did you edit, via history like Sathya suggested?

Comment: Edited direct from the history and it's all good knowing that the redirect persists even with that @dan